# How to skip to create Ubuntu Menu in status bar?

Tags: freeze, gvim, statusbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get global menu for gvim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-menu-for-gvim)

When I type `gvim` in the terminal, I wait for ~20 seconds, then I get this error message:

```
** (gvim:30499): WARNING **: Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy: Timeout was reached
```

When I move the cursor to the top statusbar, `gvim`'s menubar doesn't show up.
It doesn't matter, because I don't use `gVim` menubar.
But I do care about starting `gVim` in the terminal.

How to skip to create Ubuntu Menu in status bar when I run a GUI software(such as `gVim`)?