# How to get global application menu for gvim?

Tags: appmenu, gvim

Gvim does not have a global menu (appmenu / application menu) in 12.04,
and when starting gvim from a terminal,
the following warning appears in the terminal after 25 seconds:

```
** (gvim:20320): WARNING **: Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy: Timeout was reached
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Make the global menu for gvim work

To get global menu for gvim and to get rid of the warning message,
add this to ~/.bashrc and restart the terminal:

```
function gvim () { (/usr/bin/gvim -f "$@" &) }
```

#### Solution 2: Disable global menu for gvim

To just get rid of the warning message, you can disable the global menu, at least for gvim:

- [How do I enable or disable the global application menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10481/how-do-i-disable-the-global-application-menu)

  - [Answer #133005](https://askubuntu.com/a/133005) -
    Several options for how to disable the global menu

For example, add this to ~/.bashrc and restart the terminal:

```
alias gvim='UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= gvim'
```

#### References

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/972968
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/776499
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/987707
- https://askubuntu.com/a/132581

Comment: why the quotes around the 'all arguments'?

Comment: sorry.  I wondered why there are quotes around `"$@"` in the .bashrc function.

Comment: @xtofl: Without the quotes around "$@" you get trouble with e.g. space and literal '*' in arguments.

Comment: Out of interest, could you explain how and why the first solution works?

Comment: @ecatmur: This is how solution 1 works: The bug is related to `gvim`'s way of going into background mode. `gvim -f` keeps `gvim` in the foreground. To make the shell run `gvim` in the background we add an `&`. The parenthesis in `(foo &)` runs the command in a subshell, so that `gvim` does not become a background process of the current shell. Without parenthesis, closing the terminal by clicking the X would also kill `gvim`. `function foo () { ... }` creates a shell function. We must add `/usr/bin/` to `gvim`, otherwise we will get an infinitely recursive function. `"$@"` passes all arguments.

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/776499

Create an alias at the top of your shell init file (e.g. ~/.bashrc):

```
alias gvim="UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gvim"
```

Answer (score 3):

My Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 can work with `gvim -f`.

---

- vim-gnome: 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1+aptbuild1
- terminator:  0.96-0ubuntu1+aptbuild1
- guake: 0.4.2-7+aptbuild1

Answer (score 2):

I can add the `-f`(`--nofork`) option when start `gvim`:

```
alias gvim="gvim -f"
```

This only works for `gvim`.
`firefox` and others don't have this `-f` option.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause might be the `~/.gnome2/Vim` file. [This solution](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2009/03/09/gvim-menu-bar-missing/) (which suggests that you delete `~/.gnome2/Vim`) for the issue in Hardy Heron (before Unity) fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 13.10.

For whatever reason, `gvim -f` didn't work for me.