# Why does it take so long to start gvim?

Tags: 12.04, unity, freeze, menu, gvim

When I start `gvim`:

```
$ date; /usr/bin/gvim; date
Tue May 29 10:45:45 CST 2012

** (gvim:6030): WARNING **: Unable to create Ubuntu Menu Proxy: Timeout was reached
Tue May 29 10:46:11 CST 2012
```

To stop ubuntu menu proxy:

```
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

And test it again:

```
$ date; /usr/bin/gvim; date
Tue May 29 10:46:47 CST 2012
Tue May 29 10:47:13 CST 2012
```

No warning. But it still takes `26` seconds to start `gvim`.

Why it's so slow? Is there any season to make it happen (both 26 sec)?

---

Currently, I use:

```
alias gvim='gvim -f'
```

But I cannot detach from shell anymore.
Hope Ubuntu developer fix this problem as soon as possible.

---

```
$ dpkg --list | grep vim
ii  vim-common                             2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1                 Vi IMproved - Common files
ii  vim-gnome                              2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1                 Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GNOME2 GUI
ii  vim-gui-common                         2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1                 Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
ii  vim-runtime                            2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1                 Vi IMproved - Runtime files
ii  vim-tiny                               2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1                 Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

Comment: I have the same issue..

Comment: @PaulPraet Probably not too localized then.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also seeing this delay with gvim and rox-filer on 12.04. I added scim recently so that I could use chinese input. I have a little keyboard icon in my tray whose about box tells me is IBus 1.4.1. Selecting 'quit' off that same menu (so that the keyboard icon disappears) gives me instant gvim startup again. Starting ibus-daemon again (by "ibus-daemon -d"), I get the 26 second behaviour back.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to get global application menu for gvim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-application-menu-for-gvim)

It seems that the upstream version has already fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did the same steps as you, and the final missing piece was preventing `ibus-daemon` from starting, or killing it before I would use `gvim`:

```
killall ibus-daemon
```