# Application running in foreground?

Tags: bash, gvim

Gvim has the -f option. Its man page says,

```
-f Foreground.    For  the  GUI  version, Vim will not fork and
                  detach from the shell it was started in.
```

What does this mean?

I encountered this option when trying to make the global menu work for gvim from [How to get global application menu for gvim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132977/how-to-get-global-application-menu-for-gvim).

I thought it would be that `gvim -f file &` would show gvim and `gvim file &` wouldn't. But they both seem to have same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference should be more apparent if you try it from a terminal without the ampersands. By default, gvim goes into the background so the user can run other commands, but -f makes it wait till the editor window closes.

Comment: I do not observe this behavior. I can execute other commands from terminal while running `gvim -f file`. Maybe you can be more explicit?

Comment: @Stuart, do you have an alias for gvim? what does `type -a gvim` tell you?

Comment: -1 for me, you're right, my alias was blocking it.